# PHP issue with decoding JSON

Tags: php, json

I think it might be that its late and Im just not seeing the obvious at the moment. Im having trouble json decoding this string.

```
{"result":{"transcription":"some message","guid":"something","identifier":null}}
```

I was trying to just use plain old json_decode($String) and then tried walking through the array I thought it was creating. I also tried json_decode($String, 1) and that didnt really help either. Any ideas? I'm just trying to get the transcription value.

EDIT:

Here is the php code

```
<?php
$myFile = "test.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$Response = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
fwrite($fh, $Response->result->transcription);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

I would also like to add the reason for raw_post_data is because the post is "multipart/form-data" which seems to be the preferred method for handling multipart/form-data (at least from what my Googling pointed me to

Comment: "Trouble"? "Didn't really help"?

Comment: hey, It will really help a lot if you show how you really doing it (in php) and what errors or problems you are getting.

Comment: Could you enlighten us on what the problem is? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of additional information on the post. I wasnt getting anything. I was trying to just write the response to a text file and when I would do $array = json_decode($String) and then write $array[result] the response was blank.

Comment: `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` Contains the raw post data of the request, its not in a json format.

Comment: So the 2 dumps didnt seem to write anything, but now Mob's suggested answer is working.. So I guess Im all squared away. Thanks everyone for your help. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$l = '{"result":{"transcription":"some message","guid":"something","identifier":null}}';
$js = json_decode($l);
echo $js->result->transcription; //outputs some message
```

Comment: Ok try this `file_put_contents("file.txt",$js->result->transcription)`
Then check your directory for file.txt